# Perl: use reference has for other hash

Tags: perl, loops, hash, reference, vlookup

I'm firstly not even sure what to search for, as I know how to do this in excel but cannot find a simple way (with my limited knowledge) to do it in perl. I need to renumber a pedigree file (over 1.4 million records) and unfortunately an excel vlookup won't suffice, both due to PC power and excel spreadsheet power.

The file needs to be renumbered so that the individual does not have a lower number than the parents, so my test file looks something like this:

```
Ani | Sire | Dam
----------------
15  |   1  | 2
12  |   1  | 2
30  |  15  | 12
18  |  15  | 2
26  |  15  | 30
48  |  18  | 30
32  |  26  | 48
50  |  26  | 30
```

1 and 2 indicates an unknown parent (I will leave them as 1/2), and the renumbering begins from 10 so that the "new ids" are as follow:

```
Old_ID | New_ID
---------------
 15    | 10
 12    | 11
 30    | 12
 18    | 13
 26    | 14
 48    | 15
 32    | 16
 50    | 17
```

So the output that I would like to see would then be

```
new_ani | new_sire | new_dam
----------------------------
   10   | 1        | 2
   11   | 1        | 2
   12   | 10       | 11
   13   | 10       | 2
   14   | 10       | 12
   15   | 13       | 30
   16   | 14       | 15
   17   | 14       | 12
```

Using two hashes, I have tried (unsuccessfully) to firstly link the first column to the new IDs (which I could do), and then sire and dam column (which I cant do').

To lessen the code a bit, I left out the block calculating the new dam ids as it would be a replica of the sire. I My code thus far is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_file = .../pedigree.csv;
open (INPUT, "<", $input_file) or die "Cant open $input_file: $!";

my new_id = 0;

my %old_ped = ();
my %new_id = ();

while (<INPUT>){

        my $line = $_;
           $line =~ s/\s*$//g;

        my ($ani,$sire,$dam) = split('\,',$line);

        next if $ani eq 'db_animal' or !$ani or $ani eq 'ani';

        $old_ped{$ani}[0] = $ani;
        $old_ped{$ani}[1] = $sire;
        $old_ped{$ani}[2] = $dam;

        $new_id++;

        $new_id{$ani}[0] = $ani;
        $new_id{$ani}[1] = $new_id;

}
close INPUT;

foreach my $tt (sort keys %old_ped){

        #animal
        if ($old_ped{$tt}[0] == $new_id{$tt}[0]){
                print "$new_id{$tt}[1],";

                #sires
                if ($old_ped{$tt}[1] == 1){
                       print " 1,";
                }
                else{
                        foreach my $tt (sort keys %new_id) {
                                if ($old_ped{$tt}[1] == $nuwe_id{$tt}[0]){
                                       print "$new_id{$tt}[1],";                                           
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

# AND REPEAT SIRE BLOCK FOR DAM

print "\n";
}
```

However... I'm obviously get the wrong output as the references aren't connecting, so there are no matches for the sires (or dams).

I tried instead creating 2 additional hashes, one for sire and dam, using the sire and dam ID as the reference:

```
$sire{$sire}[0] = $sire;
$sire{$sire}[1] = $dierid;

$dam{$dam}[0] = $dam;
$dam{$dam}[1] = $dierid;
```

and using them in the foreach as follows:

```
foreach my $tt (sort keys %old_ped){

        #animal
        if ($old_ped{$tt}[0] == $new_id{$tt}[0]){
                print "$new_id{$tt}[1],";

                #sires
                if ($old_ped{$tt}[1] == 1){
                       print " 1,";
                }
                else{
                        foreach my $tt (sort keys %sire) {
                                if ($sire{$tt}[0] == $nuwe_id{$tt}[0]){
                                       print "$new_id{$tt}[1],";                                           
                                }

                        }
                }
        }

# AND REPEAT SIRE BLOCK FOR DAM

print "\n";
}
```

I'm guessing I am not using my hashes correctly, or perhaps I need to use a different loop? However, my perl knowledge is still very basic and lacking.

Any help will be tremendously appreciated!!

Comment: Your files are simple CSV? Can you include demo data that is not indented like a table please? You can [edit] your question. You can also instead of a file just use the `__DATA__` block at the end of the file, get rid of the `open` and just read from `<DATA>` instead. That will make working on your code considerable easier for the [mcve].

Comment: There's also a missing `$` at `my new_id`. Don't re-write your code into Stack Overflow please. Show your real code. We don't want to go chasing syntax errors that are not really there. I believe that's because you translated some variable names from Dutch (or Afrikaans?) to English. You did miss one in the deepest part of your loop.

Comment: Thank you - yes I did translate (Afrikaans), but will keep in mind for future to give code exactly and CSV as is! Thanks also for your answer - this is why I love stackoverflow, you really do learn a lot - especially when your knowledge is very lacking!!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is complicated. I'll first focus on a different approach, which I will explain.

You need to make two passes over the data. In the first pass, you generate a map of old ids and new ids. The algorithm to create the new id is just to start at 10 and increment, so that's simple. We can use a regular hash with the old id as the key, and the new id as the value.

In my approach, we also save the row data in this first pass into an array of array references. That way I can reuse it in the second pass. If you have a lot of records, that might not be smart as it takes a lot of memory. In that case, you would re-read the data and `print` instead of changing the values like I did.

In the second pass, we iterate the rows and simply replace all of them from the lookup hash.

- The value for *ani* is easy. Take the current value and look it up.
- The value for *sire* should only be replaced if it's not `1` or `2`. In Perl that can translate to `unless` it's smaller than `3`. Look it up in that case, else do nothing.
- The value for *dam* works the same way.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my $new_id = 10;

my %new_ids;
my @rows;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    $line =~ s/\s*$//g;

    my ( $ani, $sire, $dam ) = split( '\,', $line );

    # map old -> new
    $new_ids{$ani} = $new_id;

    # save row
    push @rows, [$ani, $sire, $dam];

    ++$new_id;
}

# iterate all rows and replace the ids
foreach my $row (@rows) {
    $row->[0] = $new_ids{$row->[0]};
    $row->[1] = $new_ids{$row->[1]} unless $row->[1] < 3;
    $row->[2] = $new_ids{$row->[2]} unless $row->[2] < 3;
}

p @rows;
__DATA__
15,1,2
12,1,2
30,15,12
18,15,2
26,15,30
48,18,30
32,26,48
50,26,30
```

My program prints the result with [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer).

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] 10,
        [1] 1,
        [2] 2
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] 11,
        [1] 1,
        [2] 2
    ],
    [2] [
        [0] 12,
        [1] 10,
        [2] 11
    ],
    [3] [
        [0] 13,
        [1] 10,
        [2] 2
    ],
    [4] [
        [0] 14,
        [1] 10,
        [2] 12
    ],
    [5] [
        [0] 15,
        [1] 13,
        [2] 12
    ],
    [6] [
        [0] 16,
        [1] 14,
        [2] 15
    ],
    [7] [
        [0] 17,
        [1] 14,
        [2] 12
    ]
]
```

---

In terms of execution time, I created a file with 1.5M records randomly with this program.

```
$ perl -E 'say join ",", int rand 10000, int rand 10000, int rand 10000 for 1 .. 1_500_000' > animals.csv
```

Running this through my code (changed to `open` the file) took about 8s on my Core i7 quadcore laptop and Perl 5.20.1.

```
$ time perl scratch.pl 
real    0m7.863s
user    0m7.260s
sys     0m0.436s
```

Comment: I don't have time right now to explain what you did wrong. But you do need to learn more about hashes. You were using arrays to look up stuff, which is extremely inefficient. That's what hashes are for.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer - will definitely go brush up on arrays and hashes!

Comment: @DonnéKruger there are a couple of perldoc pages about this stuff. http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html, http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html, http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html, http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html. In general I would suggest to get the book _Beginning Perl_ by Curtis Poe. If you know some programming and want to understand how Perl works, it's a good choice.